Strategy.exit() fails to recognize total to close after partial take profits
So, I'm having this sort of bug where position remains partially open after strategy.exit()
executes after some partial take profits.
Looks like the orders made to increase the position are not taken into account anymore for the total to be closed. Instead, if I don't do partial TP's, strategy.exit() closes also all the orders added to the original amount. What am I possibly doing wrong? Code below.


if GreenCase()    // opens a new long position
    tp1 := false  // flags for partial take profits 
    tp2 := false
    if strategy.position_size < 0  // if a short position is open, close it at market
        strategy.cancel("SELL")
        strategy.close("SELL", comment="REVERSE")
        adds := 0
        strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, pos_qty)
        strategy.exit("Buy_exit", "BUY", limit=lpp, stop=lsp)
    else if strategy.position_size == 0
        adds := 0
        strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, pos_qty)
        strategy.exit("Buy_exit", "BUY", limit=lpp, stop=lsp)
    
if RedCase()     // opens a new short position
    tp1 := false 
    tp2 := false
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        strategy.cancel("BUY")
        strategy.close("BUY", comment="REVERSE")
        adds := 0
        strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, pos_qty)
        strategy.exit("Sell_exit", "SELL", limit=spp, stop=ssp)
    else if strategy.position_size == 0
        adds := 0
        strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short, pos_qty)
        strategy.exit("Sell_exit", "SELL", limit=spp, stop=ssp)


if strategy.position_size < 0
 and close > currEntryPrice+(percentNewEntry*(currEntryPrice/100))
    adds+=1
    strategy.order("SELL", strategy.short, pos_add_qty*adds, comment="Add "+str.tostring(adds))
    tp1 := false
    tp2 := false

if strategy.position_size > 0
 and close < currEntryPrice-(percentNewEntry*(currEntryPrice/100))
    adds+=1
    strategy.order("BUY", strategy.long, pos_add_qty*adds, comment="Add "+str.tostring(adds))
    tp1 := false
    tp2 := false

if partial    // a flag in the strategyto use or not partial TP's
    if strategy.position_size > 0
        if close >= original_entry_price + partial_1_level*(original_long_TP-original_entry_price)/100
         and tp1 == false
            strategy.close("BUY", qty_percent = partial_1_percent, immediately=true, comment="Partial TP 1", alert_message="")
            tp1 := true
        if close >= original_entry_price + partial_2_level*(original_long_TP-original_entry_price)/100
         and tp2 == false
            strategy.close("BUY", qty_percent = partial_2_percent, immediately=true, comment="Partial TP 2", alert_message="")
            tp2 := true
    if strategy.position_size < 0
        if close <= original_entry_price - partial_1_level*(original_entry_price-original_short_TP)/100
         and tp1 == false
            strategy.close("SELL", qty_percent = partial_1_percent, immediately=true, comment="Partial TP 1", alert_message="")
            tp1 := true
        if close <= original_entry_price - partial_2_level*(original_entry_price-original_short_TP)/100
         and tp2 == false
            strategy.close("SELL", qty_percent = partial_2_percent, immediately=true, comment="Partial TP 2", alert_message="")
            tp2 := true



Note that the partial TP's qty is 50% the current position size for both of them.  What strategy.exit() closes is the original size minus the two TP's. It deliberately ignores additional orders.

We are going to need a minimal reproducible example if you want help. And also, ticker, exchange, timeframe, date and timezone etc.
